# How to give borders to jspdf autotable content generated dynamically as in template

Tags: angular, jspdf-autotable

i am using jspdf autotable to generate pdf, but i am failing to put borders as in the template.
Can anyone help me to sort it out.
i need the pdf viewed to be as in template.

Need border of header to have 2 border lines as shown here in template.

[image]

Last rows of total to be displayed like this.

[image]

TS:

```
captureScreen() {
    this.displayTable = true;
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var col = ["2006", "Budgeted Operating Expenses ", 'Exclude', 'Expenses'];
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.budget.length; i++) {
      var temp = []
      for (var key in this.items.budget[i]) {
        temp.push(this.items.budget[i][key])
      }
      rows.push(temp);
    }
    doc.text(100, 10, this.items.title.title);
    doc.text(20, 20, "Insert Property Name Here");
    doc.setFont("Times New Roman");
    doc.setFontSize(12);
    doc.text(20, 30, "Tenant:");
    doc.text(40, 30,  this.items.owner.company);

    doc.text(20, 40, "Address:");
    doc.text(40, 40,this.items.owner.address);

    doc.text(20, 50, "Suite:");
    doc.text(40, 50,this.items.owner.suite);


    doc.autoTable(col, rows,{
      tableLineColor: [189, 195, 199],
      tableLineWidth: 0.75,
    theme:"plain",  
    startY: 60,
    margin: {
        top: 60
    },
   headerStyles: {
        //Not getting what to be done here
    },
    });
    document.getElementById("convertToPdf").setAttribute('src', doc.output('datauri'))
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dh9cbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**jsPdf-autotable** has no tools "from the box" for creating cell borders in (*top || right || bottom || left*) or double bourder.
You may use **jspdf** methods for manualy paint necessary elements (lines):

```
doc.autoTable(col, rows, {
        tableLineColor: [189, 195, 199],
        tableLineWidth: 0.75,
        theme: "plain",
        startY: 60,
        margin: {
            top: 60
        },
        drawRow: (row, data) => {
            //-------------------------------
            // Paint double lines bellow cell
            //-------------------------------
            let firstCell = row.cells[0];
            let secondCell = row.cells[1];
            if (firstCell.text == 'Total due anually') {
               let borderLineOffset = 1;
               const columnWidth = data.table.columns[3].width;
               data.doc.line(data.cursor.x - columnWidth, data.cursor.y + row.height - borderLineOffset / 2, data.cursor.x, data.cursor.y + row.height - borderLineOffset / 2);
               data.doc.line(data.cursor.x - columnWidth, data.cursor.y + row.height + borderLineOffset / 2, data.cursor.x, data.cursor.y + row.height + borderLineOffset / 2);
            }
            //-------------------------------
            // Paint footer line
            //-------------------------------
            if (secondCell.text == 'Totally sales Tax') {
                data.doc.line(data.cursor.x - data.table.width, data.cursor.y + row.height, data.cursor.x, data.cursor.y + row.height);
                data.doc.line(data.cursor.x - data.table.width, data.cursor.y + row.height, data.cursor.x, data.cursor.y + row.height);
            }
        },
        drawHeaderRow: (head, data) => {
            //---------------------------------------
            // Write the line at the bottom of header
            //---------------------------------------
            data.doc.line(data.cursor.x, data.cursor.y + head.height, data.cursor.x + data.table.width, data.cursor.y + head.height);
        }
    });
```

Here you may found other elements for paint them in pdf.
[jsPdf docs](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#line)
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqiuxd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for response, but i dont need that middle lines from the headers

Comment: ya thank you, but the data will come dynamically so we cant predict these will be the  properties and al

Comment: @Bhrungarajni As you can see, I add lines based not on the static coordinates, but on the coordinates of the cells that were generated based on the data. I define these cells by their unique field (inner text), if the set of basic data in the table changes, but the cells with these unique fields remain, the lines will be drawn where necessary automatically

Comment: no no thats correct, i have edited my stackblitz with your code, in that i removed table border, can you pls help me to get a border above the header same as in below header.

Comment: How can i give black color instead of grey there, is grey default color?

Comment: i have voted and accepted your answer, i need those 2 changes can u pls help me out to achieve

Comment: Functions `data.doc.setLineWidth(0.7)` and `data.doc.setDrawColor(0,0,0)`. See updated example: [StackBlits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwbvj4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: i have one doubt in this, can you please help me to clarify?

Comment: for second line you must add vertical offset

Comment: here we have used Total due anually, if incase from backend different data comes means this wont work right? so how can we assign borders via rows calculation from last?

Comment: and cant drawHeader() be written outside the createpdf function and cal it in createPdf? bcz that drawheader i am using in 4 template functions so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190490/discussion-between-ivanes-and-bhrungarajni).

Comment: @Ivanes, it's a good sample..But I have a question on how to add the border line-height for each column o the table. Thanks